# Restarting all activities Android

Tags: android

I want to make my own app so that it restarts when the user deletes images from my gridView. This means, when I have two activities open, when the user clicks a button, all activities are closed, and after that are reopened, as if nothing happened.

GridViewAdapter

```
 public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ImageView image;
// Declare variables
private Activity activity;
private String[] filepath;
private String[] filename;
CheckableLayout l;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
    activity = a;
    filepath = fpath;
    filename = fname;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
    // Locate the TextView in gridview_item.xml
    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
     image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

    // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position
    File file = new File(filepath[position]);
    Picasso.with(activity).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(image);


    // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position


    // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
  //  image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return vi;
}

}
```

And this is my onActivityResult , after the user select his image from gallery

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    // get image from external storage

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXTERNAL_IMAGE) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            InputStream inputStream;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                bitmapArray.add(image);

                OutputStream output;
                // Find the SD Card path
                File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                int count2 = 0;
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
                count2 = settings.getInt("SNOW_DENSITY", 0); //0 is the default value
                String paranteza1 = "(";
                String paranteza2 = ")";
                int count1 = new File("/mnt/sdcard" + nameAlbum).listFiles().length;
                count1 = count1 + 1;
                String nameImage = "Wallpaper_" + count1 + ".jpg";
                for (int j = 0; j < listFile.length; j++) {
                    FileNameStrings[j] = listFile[j].getName();


                    if (FileNameStrings[j].equals(nameImage)) {
                        nameImage = "Wallpaper_" + count1 + paranteza1 + count2 + paranteza2 + ".jpg";
                        count2++;
                        settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putInt("SNOW_DENSITY", count2);
                        editor.commit();
                        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                            FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
                            if (FileNameStrings[i].equals(nameImage)) {

                                nameImage = "Wallpaper_" + count1 + paranteza1 + count2 + paranteza2 + ".jpg";
                                count2++;
                                settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
                                editor = settings.edit();
                                editor.putInt("SNOW_DENSITY", count2);
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                count2++;
                File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                        + nameAlbum);

                // Retrieve the image from the res folder


                // Create a name for the saved image
                file = new File(dir, nameImage);


                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + nameAlbum);

            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listFile = file.listFiles();
                // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
                FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
                // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
                FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                    // Get the path of the image file
                    FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    // Get the name image file
                    FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
                    // Locate the GridView in gridview_main.xml
                    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                    // Pass String arrays to LazyAdapter Class
                    adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);
                    // Set the LazyAdapter to the GridView
                    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want your application to restart ?because your solution seems to be a little "brutal"

Comment: if you really wanted to close all activities use System.exit(0);

Comment: @RaviGadipudi ok , but how can I reopen them like it was before without toching anything?

Comment: @Kassisdion if I delete some images from my gridView , when I add again more images , in my gridView will show the same images like before , but if I clik on them , will show the images I just added, and if I restart my app manually my gridView is just fine.. that's why I want to kill my all activities , and reopen them

Comment: My understanding about your question is. You want allow user to delete images from grid view and show them the same activity with updated results?

Comment: I think you have mad a mistake because you can delete and add image from your array ^^. Can you show us your code ? (your custom adapter or your activity ?)

Comment: I agree with Kassisdion. Don't restart the app, that's bad practice. If the images don't disappear when you remove them, maybe there's an 'invalidate' missing.

Comment: I edited my question :) thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got you right, this should work perfectly: use intents with flags.

```
Intent DeleteVideo = new Intent(getActivity(), Actvity2.class);
DeleteVideo.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getActivity().startActivity(DeleteVideo);
finish;
```

If I missed somthing please read [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
.

Comment: I strongly advise against this. Restarting an app or an activity because you want to refresh an image is bad practice. Just remove the image from the gridview after the user deleted it, and add a new image when the user adds one.

Comment: I assumed he wanted exactly to restart the activity an kill any other activity on the stack .

Comment: He wanted to restart because that's the only solution he saw. Restarting an app is evil, unless under extremely unusual circumstances. Whatever Activity or Fragment or View you have, it's always possible to seamlessly update, remove and add content.

Comment: I use this method when i need t clear any user related activity for security  concerns and I have to say i use it with an activity that is NOT the root activity so dose not cause my app to close , however i totally agree with you that killing the app should only be called when necessary .

Comment: I have used it only once, in over eight years of programming Android.

Comment: Christine I want your help in this issue , [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830682/gridviewadapter-doesnt-clean-up?noredirect=1#comment53499222_32830682)   in this link I asked the same issue I tried to solve with this question , but I want to solve it properly .If you have some time , please give it a view! Thanks!!!